# Grafana: How to check in a query if a single variable is selected or more?

Tags: sql, postgresql, grafana, grafana-templating, grafana-variable

I have a dashboard where I have a variable `X` for which one or more values can be selected. The data source is postgresql. I have a panel where I make a query to show some trends using `X`. Up till this point everything is working.

Now, I need to check if the the user has select only one value of the variable `X`. if the user has selected only one value, then we need to change the column value slightly. How do I check if the user has selected only 1 value? Is there a grafana construct for that? or should I do it via SQL purely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found a way to check that:

```
coalesce(array_length(ARRAY[$X],1),0) = 1
```

This works for postgreSQL. If you know the above functions, it is pretty self-explanatory.